# kendo treeview + grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, grid, kendo-ui, treeview

i have treeview and grid on one page. 
treeview has two node levels. level 1 are chapter nodes and they can have several level 2 nodes under them. i want, when i click on level 1 node, to display text description of that chapter and when i click on level 2 node it has to display grid with all the data in it.
i am using visual studio 2012 and app is mvc 4...
so far i have made treeview-grid functional without this functionality. when i click on level 2 nodes it populates the grid fine. 
i am new in this so any help is good...

Comment: You need to add your code, explain what you're trying to do and what isn't working.

Comment: i didn't think that adding code will help explain because my problem was more conceptual than code it self. in meantime i had i strike of lightning and solved problem myself. i simply made two views. on one there is only treeview and text(description of chapter -if level 1 node is clicked) and on another one there is treeview and grid for showing data (if level 2 node is clicked). and that's it. i suppose that to someone who worked with mvc and c# that was simple and that is the way things should be done but for me, since i am new in this it was big problem... which i solved!! :-)